# How to check event Listeners on an element in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, prototypejs, dom-events

I have a page that has some td elements in a table that the user can click and drag to reorder.  The page is built using prototype.  In everything but IE9, this works, but in IE9, when I try to click and drag, I just highlight some of the things on the page.  My suspicion is that the handler isn't actually attaching to the td element.

Is there a way to check what listeners are attached to an element in IE9?

(The code is also not in a place that I can share it, which is why I have not posted any.)

Edit: It turns out I was actually using prototype 1.6.1, and the problem was ultimately caused by that not knowing that IE9 and IE10 are less awful than < 9.  It's going to be a much bigger fix than I thought.

Comment: console.log(myElem.onclick) ? And then just test as many event listeners as you can think of.

Comment: There may also be a way to view the dom element object's properties in the web inspector (F12). Not sure where though.

Comment: I can see the dom element's properties, U just don't know where to look. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node You may find your answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest PrototypeJS (1.7.1) stores the event observers in an Event Cache

So for example a `<div>` with id 'mydiv'

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

After you create an observer via the `observe()` or `on()` methods like this

```
$('mydiv').observe('click',function(){
    alert('Click Happened');
});
```

The click property of the Event cache will be set like below

```
Event.cache[$('mydiv')._prototypeUID].click
```

However this might not be the source of your problem as you said it is working in all other browsers except IE9 - is there a way you can extract some of the code and put it into a JSFiddle and then post the link?